# initiate sp_databases for a c# listbox

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have found that using `sp_databases`, it might possibly be able to populate a `ListBox` with all the databases on my remote server.

How I would incorporate that code on my form to get it to work properly?

Comment: Connect to the database, run the SP and get the results and display them. Once you have a more specific problem, you may get better answers.

Comment: ASP.NET, Windows Forms, WPF, C#/Framework version?

Comment: 5 downvotes?? harsh... the question does have an answer

Comment: +1 I feel this is a valid question, I believe the original wording of the question was more of a English as a second language barrier than actual poor intent.

Answer (score 3):

From this namespace:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Here is a solution:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("connection string to yer database"))
{
    SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("exec sp_databases", cn);
    SqlDataReader rdr;

    cn.Open();
    rdr = cm.ExecuteReader();
    if (rdr.HasRows())
    {
       while (rdr.Read())
       {
           listBox1.Items.Add(rdr["DATABASE_NAME"].ToString());                
       }
    }
    rdr.Close();
}
```

As for connection string.  Here is a good reference:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

Comment: You shouldn't call close and dispose manually, you should use those inside of using statements. What would happen if dr["DATABASE_NAME"].ToString() blew up for some reason? You'd have a resource leak.

Comment: ok, good information... I've updated answer.  According to microsoft documentation the rdr should still be closed manually.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: sorry guys.  im doing this in c#.  Do I need to add any references?  I just add the connection string for my server only?  Like SqlConnection("Server=Server01")

Comment: @lazyDBA +1 This is getting much closer, I do think that SqlCommand, and I definitely know the data reader is IDisposable. You can choose to manually call close on the reader still (honestly I don't think I ever have personally though) @user819924 you will most likely need references to System.Data (I think, resharper always tells me standard references) and yes you can put in a raw connection string in your code however the optimal solution is to put the connection strings in your web.config or app.config and only supply the connection string NAME in the sql connection.